# The data couldn’t be read because it is missing

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to decode a JSON I get from a server. But I always get this error:

```
The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.
```

I don't understand why I get this error, I looked and saw few answers but nothing solved my problem, I can't figure it out.
This is the response I get from the server (as shown in Postman):

```
{
"email": "new@user.com",
"username": "newuser",
"user_rating": 0,
"store_id": "",
"state": "",
"city": "",
"address": "",
"zip_code": 0,
"user_id": "user_id_test",
"created_on": 1585933800
}
```

This is my Swift code:

```
func getUser(id: String, completion: @escaping(User?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let urlParams = "/?id=\(id)"
    guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + "getUser" + urlParams) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(nil, error)
            debugPrint(error) //TODO: Handle error.
            return
        }

        guard let jsonData = data else { return }
        print(String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: .utf8))
        do {
            let user = try self.decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)
            completion(user, nil)
        } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    }).resume()
}
```

This line: `print(String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: .utf8))` prints:

```
Optional("{\"email\":\"new@user.com\",\"username\":\"newuser\",\"user_rating\":0,\"store_id\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"address\":\"\",\"zip_code\":0,\"user_id\":\"user_id_test\",\"created_on\":1585933800}")
```

Which looks okay to me.

This is the User Struct I'm trying to decode:

```
struct User: Codable {

let email: String!
let username: String!
let rating: Float!
let storeID: String?
let state: String?
let city: String?
let address: String?
let zipCode: Int
let uuid: String!
let createdOn: TimeInterval!

}
```

Comment: `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)` you'll get a better message pointing out exactly what's wrong. I tested and didn't get an issue, if you use de `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`, but what is `self.decoder`?

Comment: self.decoder is just a JSONDecoder I use in the whole class so I made one instance of it. Thanks you the answer :) I changed to print(error) instead of localizedDescription and I can now see the problem.

Comment: Would you mind giving the new error message then? Or if you fixed it, how to did you fixed it? Remember that someone with the same issue can find your question, but not finding an answer.

Comment: Sure, sorry. I accidentally gave the json parameters wrong names. for example, instead of zipCode I set it as zip_code. totally forgot about that, and the .localizedDescription didn't show the problem. after changing to only print the error as you said, I saw it.